# How to create a common component for reducing similar separate components creation in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and learning about creating rest api with react. I was trying to fetch data from database and populate it into a select component. Well I could manage to do that. But the fact is I have created two components like this.

```
const REQ_URL = '/api/get-code-list/';

class CodeListComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            options: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch(REQ_URL,{
            method:'GET'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>{
            this.setState({
                options:data
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <select name="code_list" class="form-control">
          {this.state.options.map(item => (
                <option key={item.id} value={item.code}>{item.name}</option>
                )
          )}
          </select>  
        )
    };
}

const REQ_URL = '/api/get-location-list/';

class LocationListComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            options: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch(REQ_URL,{
            method:'GET'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>{
            this.setState({
                options:data
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <select name="location_list" class="form-control">
                    {this.state.options.map(item => (
                <option key={item.id} value={item.code}>{item.name}</option>
                )
          )}
          </select>  
        )
    };
}
```

My question is both of the components are very much similar. So I was thinking why not create a single common component and pass the url through a parameter when calling the component. 
Instead of doing

```
<div class="form-group">
    <CodeListComponent/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <LocationListComponent/> 
</div>
```

I want to do like this and pass the url but could not get it how it can be done.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <CustomListComponent/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <CustomListComponent/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you will need a `url` and `name` prop. Then, be sure to use those prop values in your `CustomListComponent`. Also added an example for handling the change events:

```
class CustomListComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    options: []
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch(this.props.url,{
      method:'GET'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          options: data
        });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { name, onChange } = this.props;
    return(
      <select name={name} class="form-control" onChange={onChange}>
        {this.state.options.map(item => (
            <option key={item.id} value={item.code}>{item.name}</option>
          )
        )}
      </select>
    )
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <CustomListComponent
    url="/api/get-code-list/"
    name="code_list"
    onChange={this.handleCodeListChange}
  />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <CustomListComponent
    url="/api/get-location-list/"
    name="location_list"
    onChange={this.handleLocationListChange}
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make your call to the external URL in the parent and then pass the list into your list component as a prop. This seems like the best way to do it in my opinion.

**Edit:** For clarification, you could have the parent of your list make the API call to retrieve the array, and then pass the array as props to your list like this:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        /* make API call */
        myArr = someAPICall(url)

        this.setState({myArr});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyListComponent arr={this.state.myArr} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't fully got it...Can you provide an example?

Comment: I added an example in my response. Hopefully that helps!